Extended Stabilizer Simulator:Get Statistics of the quantum circuit
I am trying to simulate a Clifford+T gate quantum circuit using extended stabilizer simulator. But as i see it only returns the measurement output. The measurement output(counts) depends on the shots that we provide to the simulator. While for small circuit this might seems good enough but when I am doing simulation for say 30 qubits there will be 2^30 possbile outcome and the measurement will not be good for deducing any information. I wanted to know if there is any way we can get statistics of the simulation.

I found that they represent a state by stabilizer generators. Getting access to this Generator function will also help to get the exact statistical information.
Or, any other method to get the statistical information for the quantum circuit.

I am trying to do some experiment on T-design so getting accurate statistics of the circuit is important than measurement.
